# Как заставить Unity3D различать клики в интерфейсах IBeginDragHandler и т.д

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть скрипт на перетягивание предметов в инвентаре. Он работает с помощью интерфейсов IBeginDragHandler, IDragHandler и IEndDragHandler. Как заставить Unity различать, какую кнопку мыши я нажал. Я могу перетягивать предметы зажав правую или левую кнопку мыши, но я хочу что бы при зажатии правой кнопки мыши я мог просто перетягивать предметы. А при нажатии левой кнопки мыши мои предметы разделялись на 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно добавить проверку ввода (только не как у предыдущего оратора - зачем вам каждый `Update` знать, чего вы нажали, если можно проверять при нажатии?) и интерфейс `IPointerClickHandler` для "разделения" :) 
В вашем случае это:

```
public void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
    {
         //тут логика начала перетаскивания. и какой-нибудь флажок _isDraging = true,
         //который проверяется в остальных методах перетягивания.
    }
}

public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData eventData);
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
         //тут логика разделения.
    }
}
```

Метод `OnPointerClick` сработает только, если курсор был опущен и поднят над одним и тем же элементом.

Answer (score 1):

Тогда для начала,до всех действий определите ту самую,нажатую игроком кнопку :

https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/ScriptReference/Input.GetMouseButtonDown.html

```
// Пример
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    void Update() {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            Debug.Log("Pressed left click."); // либо ваш код

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
            Debug.Log("Pressed right click."); // либо ваш код

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(2))
            Debug.Log("Pressed middle click."); // либо ваш код

    }
}
```